# Is there a quicker way to add column or change fields in SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package

We have 10 slightly different SSIS packages that transfer data from one database to another. Whenever we make a change to the first db, such as adding in a new field or changing a property of said field such as extending a varchar's length, we have to update the packages as well.

Each of these packages have a long flow with multiple merge joins, sorts, conditional statements, etc. If the field that needs to be changed is at the beginning of the process, I have to go through each merge and update it with the new change and each time I do so, it takes a few minutes to process, then I'm on to the next one. As I get near the end, the process takes longer and longer to compute for each merge join. Doing this for 10 different packages, even if they are done at the same time, still takes upwards of 3 hours. This is time consuming and very monotonous. There's got to be a better way, right?

Comment: If you can describe your logic well enough, then you could use something like Biml or EzAPI to autogenerate your packages. Then you can make all the changes you want and packages are created based on the current metadata, not the previous. Personally, I'm a fan of the Biml approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIML is very good for this.  BIML is an XML-based technology which translates to dtsx packages.  BIMLScript is BIML interleaved with c# or vb to provide control flow logic, so you can create multiple packages/package elements based on conditions.  You can easily query the table structure or custom metadata, such that if you are only doing db to db transformations, you can make structural changes to the database(s) and regenerate your SSIS packages without having to do any editing.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. The metadata that SSIS generates makes it very awkward when data sources change. You can go down the road of dynamically generated packages, but it's not ideal.

Your other option is damage reduction. Consider whether you could implement the Canonical Data Model pattern:

http://www.eaipatterns.com/CanonicalDataModel.html

It would involve mapping the data to some kind of internal format immediately on receiving it, possibly via a temporary table or cache, and then only using your internal format from then on. Then you map back to your output format at the end of processing.

While this does increase the overall complexity of your package, it means that an external data source changing will only affect the transforms at the beginning and end of your processing, which may well save you lots of time in the long run.